# How to add timeout and poll for a code in java?

Tags: java, timeout, polling

**Here is my code**:

```
public class TimerDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // creating timer task, timer
        TimerTask tasknew = new TimerTask() {
           
            @Override
            public void run() {
           
                    URL url = null;
                    try {
                        url = new URL("http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?alpha_two_code=CN");
                        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }  }
 };
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        // scheduling the task at interval
        timer.schedule(tasknew,0, 60000);
```

I am polling this code for every minute

My question is **how to add timeout for this**?

*For example*: Poll for every minute and timeout is 5 minutes? How to give time out for 5 minutes in above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `TimerTask`, you can check how much time has passed and call `timer.cancel()` to stop it.

```
public class TimerDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final long TIMEOUT = 5*60000; // 5 minutes

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // creating timer task, timer
    TimerTask tasknew = new TimerTask() {   

      @Override
      public void run() {
    
        // Do some work here
        // ...        

        long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        if (elapsed >= TIMEOUT) {
          timer.cancel();
        }
      }
    };

  // scheduling the task at interval
  timer.schedule(tasknew, 0, 60000);
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to check for 5 minutes in the timertask? I tried but no luck . Edgar Domingues

Comment: Added an example

Comment: It worked pefectly , But why am i not able to handle exception? For example if its a timeout i should get timeout exception right? is it possible?  Edgar Domingues

Comment: This doesn't throw an exception. It run the TimerTask every minute and cancels it after five minutes.

Comment: I have given timeout 5 minutes and polling 1 minute, run method is getting called once,What might be the issue? Edgar Domingues

Comment: Please open a new question with your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66090917/run-method-of-a-timer-task-is-getting-called-only-once @Edgar Domingues Can you check the question?

Comment: Can you check my new question using above link? @Edgar Domingues